# How to use lambda functions with cross-index computation when iterating dataframes columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a pandas data frame, `df`, with one of the columns called `val` to which I apply a cross index computation:

```
import pandas as pd
sensor_data = {'Sensor': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'val': [20, 2 , 2, 19, 18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(sensor_data)

# Cross index computation:
cross_index_computation_result = []
for i in range(1, len(df['val'])):
    cross_index_computation_result.append(df['val'][i-1] * df['val'][i])
print(cross_index_computation_result)
>> [40, 4, 38, 342]
```

Especially with regard to `lambda` functions like `Map`, `Filter` and `Reduce`, which are way faster than using a simple for loop with index access,
is there a more efficient way to perform cross-index computations on a dataframe column interation?

I know this is wrong syntax but something like:
`cross_index_computation_result = list(map(lambda x: x[i-1] * x[i], df['val']))`

Answer (score 0):

You could compute the values within Numpy (there is possibly an ever more efficient way to do this): -> In the code below, the data is reshaped, then the various Numpy functions are used to compute the product

```
reshaped = np.reshape(df.val.to_numpy(), (2,2))

reshaped[0].prod(), np.diag(reshaped[::-1]).prod(), reshaped[1].prod()
(40, 38, 342)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) ?

```
print((df['val'] * df['val'].shift(-1)).dropna().astype(int).to_list())

[40, 4, 38, 342]
```